# How to pull value from dictionary that pushed to Airflow XCom

Tags: airflow

Let's say I have some Airflow operator, and one of the arguments to the operator needs to take the value from the xcom. I've managed to do it in the following way -

```
 f"model_id={{{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='train', key='{task_id}')}}}}"
```

Where `model_id` is the argument name to the docker operator the airflow runs and `task_id` is the name of the key for that value in the xcom.

Now I want to do something more complex and save under `task_id` a dictionary instead of one value, and be able to take it from it somehow.

Is there a similar way to do it to the one I mentioned above? something like -

```
 f"model_id={{{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='train', key='{task_id}')}}}}[value]"
```

Comment: try to set render_template_as_native_obj=True in your dag.

Answer (score 1):

By default, all the template_fields are rendered as strings.
However Airflow offers the option to render fields as native Python objects.

You will need to set you DAG as:

```
dag = DAG(
    ...
    render_template_as_native_obj=True,
)
```

You can see example of how to render as dictionary in the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/operators.html#rendering-fields-as-native-python-objects).

Comment: My problem is that I don't need all the arguments but be able to take one of them. Can I use that and somehow take one of the values with a specific key?

Comment: My suggestion: push to xcom only what you really need. There is no point in pushing values that you have no use of.

Answer (score 0):

My answer for a similar issue was this.

```
f"model_id={{{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='train', key='{task_id}')[value]}}}}"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).